# google app engine Unable to create a github deploy pipeline

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a git repo set up and configured on the console, but when ever I try to create the pipeline under source code - release (deploy source only) it says "Failed to create the pipeline."  If any one has encountered this and fixed I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: This is kind of unclear, can you explain a bit better what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an ongoing issue for this....
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11102

Answer (score 0):

You have to have permission as an owner for the project you want to create pipeline. Please check permission under your project name by clicking "Permissions" and make sure you are the owner ("Is owner" status), not you have the "can edit" status under permission column. Please post if it resolves the issue.